# Composite list from two (or more) columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

Looking for ideas how to approach this automatically. Here is an example to explain it.

I have a column A on a sheet containing fruit types, eg, banana, apple, orange, fig, kiwifruit.

I have column B on another sheet containing, eg, blueberry, strawberry, fig, custard apple, banana.

I want a single column X of fruit with no duplicates. I can do this manually by just copying one column, pasting it on the bottom of the other, then removing duplicates.

However, any time I add an entry to either column, I have to do all this again.

Is there any way to have Excel automatically create column X from columns A and B, even if entries are added to A or B?

Comment: do the operation manually and record it as a macro. You will get your VBA script automatically

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest to make lists unique first and to merge them afterwards. Here are two links:

To make lists unique, use a trick with the LOOKUP and the COUNTIF functions. The function below is for the first value of unique list. The original list is at *$B$3:$B$9* and the formula is at *$D$2*

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($D$2:D5,$B$3:$B$9)=0),$B$3:$B$9)
```

The next step is to merge them with the INDEX and the ROW functions. The formula below assumes that two lists are at *$B$2:$B$5* and *$D$2:$D$7*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$5,ROWS($F$1:F1)),IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$7,ROWS($F$1:F1)-ROWS($B$2:$B$5)),””))
```

For detailed information please follow the links:

[1. Make list unique](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/get-unique-items-from-list/)

[2. Merge two lists](https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/merge-columns-using-formula/)

Comment: This seems to be a [link-only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) answer. You should provide context to all your links, otherwise the OP will have no idea what they are clicking into. Also, the link can break and the answer becomes worthless later.

Comment: @TiagoCaldeira Hey, thanks for the warning. I updated my answer with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why you have two separate lists to start? It would help to know some context for your process.

The reason I ask is that you could reverse your process quite easily, which gives a neat automated solution. Create one long list with two columns: "Fruit Types", and then something like "Category" (A and/or B). Then you can keep one long list of unique values and use a `LOOKUP` or `INDEX MATCH` to generate your two separate lists elsewhere. They would always updated based on a wingle change you make to the main list.

Comment: The fruit was just a simple example which I hoped would be able to be used in the real case. I actually have three datasets. Each one contains lines with a bacteria type, its serial number, the serial number of its parent and some other numerical information to be used in calculations. I have each dataset on a different worksheet. The datasets overlap, ie, there are some entries common to all datasets, and some are unique to a single dataset.

Comment: What I have done manually is to make up a composite list of bacteria/number/parent. I then use LOOKUP functions to search each of the sheets for the other data to be used in calculations.

I want to distribute this spreadsheet to others with different data. These people are not familiar with Excel, so I want to avoid copy/paste/remove duplicates instructions if I can.